# Facebook Android Client to Custom App notification

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, notifications, apprequests

I am developing an Android app that connects to the Facebook Open Graph via the Facebook Android SDK. My apps sends apprequests to users to invite them to open the app (if they have them or install it).

My problem seems to be the notifications I sent via the app requests dialog using the SDK don't seem to show up in the Notifications popup in the native Facebook Android app, but I can see them fine if I login via the Facebook Website. As expected, clicking the notification on the web, takes me to my app's Facebook Canvas page, but I was wondering why in the world that does not show on the Facebook Android client.

Using version 1.5 seems to show just like in the web site, but trying the latest (1.8) does not show the notification at all!

Let me know should anybody know of a workaround to this issue or if there's any missing configurations on my Facebook App settings for it to display, given the only limitation I had faced before was not having a Canvas URL defined for the app and after having set it, it started showing fine, but not for the Android 1.8 client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually just found the answer to my own question:

The notifications won't show for any app requests at all if you don't have a Canvas URL setup in your Facebook App and they won't show for mobile clients if your app does not have a Mobile Web Url configured.

So in order to be fully enabled for apprequests to show you need to make sure you go to `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{YOUR_APP_ID}/summary` and set both the Canvas URL and the Mobile Web URL of your Facebook (even though you might not have a fully compatible web app to point to).